# Understanding this Ruby Program to find prime numbers

Tags: ruby, primes

I am new to Ruby, and I have been reading over this program that finds us prime numbers.

This example came in a textbook, after talking about loops (while & until) it showed this example.

I find it pretty confusing. What is the purpose of the prime_flag? 
Why is J set as 2?

(j <= i / 2) -- This one I don't understand.

j = j + 1 -- what is the purpose of this.

My apologies for the long question, but any help is greatly appreciated. Please and thank you.

```
# Initialize our counter
i = 1

# i: [0, 100]
while (i <= 100)
  # Initialize prime flag 
  prime_flag = true
  j = 2
  # Test divisibility of i from [0, i/2]
  while (j <= i / 2)
    # puts " i ==> " to i.to_s + " j ==> " + j.to_s 
    if (i % j == 0)
      prime_flag = false
      # break
    end 
    j = j + 1
  end
  # We found a prime!
  if prime_flag
    puts "Prime ==> " + i.to_s"
  end 
  # Increment the counter
  i += 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop is counting from 2 to half of `i` and testing to see if it is prime.

> Why is J set as 2?

A prime number is a number that has no factors aside from one and itself. If `j` started at 1, of course 1 is a factor of the number. If we included 1, then the code would think none of the numbers are prime because it would consider 1 a factor.

> (j <= i / 2)

The while loop checks up to half of the number. Technically, you only need to check up to the square root of the number.

> j = j + 1 -- what is the purpose of this.

We need to increment `j` to move on the the next number. The program is essentially doing something like:

1. Start with `j` at 2.
2. Is `i` divisible by `j`?

   1. Yes? Clear the prime flag.
3. Set `j` to the next number, 3.
4. Is `i` divisible by `j`?

   1. Yes? Clear the prime flag.
5. Repeat up to half of `i`

In the example you posted, `break` is commented out, and I'm not sure why. The `break` would be a good thing to do. That basically says, "OK, we found a factor for `i`, we don't need to keep looping looking for more factors.

> What is the purpose of the prime_flag?

The `prime_flag` is being used to track if it has found any factors for `i`. The variable starts off as true, so "Yes", assume the number is prime. As soon as we find a factor, it sets it to false, indicating that `i` is not prime.

Comment: j <= i/2 (If we only need to find its square root, why is this line of code written?

Comment: @RedisPurple it's likely the author of the text book did not know that. Checking up to half of i doesn't make the code "wrong" exactly, just inefficient.