# Understanding this Ruby program concerned with prime numbers

Tags: ruby, primes

This is a program that came from a textbook:

```
# Initialize our counter
i = 1

# i: [0, 100]
while (i <= 100)          
  # Initialize prime flag 
  prime_flag = true
  j = 2
  # Test divisibility of i from [0, i/2]
  while (j <= i / 2)     
    # puts " i ==> " to i.to_s + " j ==> " + j.to_s 
    if (i % j == 0)       
     prime_flag = false
     # break
    end 
    j = j + 1
  end
    # We found a prime!
    if prime_flag
      puts "Prime ==> " + i.to_s
    end 
    # Increment the counter
    i += 1
end
```

The `while (j <= i / 2)` introduces a new loop. What if we are trying to find prime numbers. Why is this written? Prime numbers don't have square roots. What is the purpose of `j` being `<= i / 2`? I do not understand why `j` is introduced.

Comment: That code is not at all Ruby-like. What text did it come from?

Comment: Regarding `j <= i/2`, if `j` is found to be prime so is `i/j`, so there is no need to examine `j > i/2`. In fact, the bound is actually much tighter. You only need to examing `j` for which `j <= Math.sqrt(j)`.

Comment: Thanks... This text came from "Computer Science Programming Basics in Ruby..." [Frieder, Frieder & Grossman]

Comment: OMG. My advise would be to burn this book in the chimney. This is not ruby code, this is [tag:c] code, poorly and lazily translated to ruby syntax.

Comment: Really? It's that bad? -- bear in mind that this is a book that's made for rookies to understand "basics"...

Comment: In my second comment the last expression should be `j <= Math.sqrt(i).floor`.

Comment: I was kinder than @mudasobwa. That fact that it is aimed at rookies is even more of a reason to incinerate it. I looked up the book on Amazon. There were no reviews, but there's a newer book on the same subject, for which two of the authors are the same. I browsed it and found some Ruby code (having numerous `for` loops!) that was equally bad as that above. The first review gave the book five starts. It began, "This book was definitely a source of clarity for my Computer Science Using Ruby course at Georgetown University." (cont.)

Comment: That raised suspicions in my mind. Sure enough, one author, Gideon Frieder, is a professor in Georgetown's Computer Science department. (Another heads a computer science lab there)! This (forcing students to use inferior books to make money) happens all the time. I wouldn't be surprised to see a new edition of the book every couple of years, just to make the earlier ones obsolete.

Comment: Thanks Cary. I will try other material.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding this Ruby Program to find prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713404/understanding-this-ruby-program-to-find-prime-numbers)

Comment: @mudasobwa Have you read the book? Unfair to criticise a book unless you have.

Comment: @Cary The book is titled _CS Programming Basics in Ruby_ so perhaps the emphasis is more on programming rather than Ruby per se? If that's the case then learning about `for` loops would be beneficial as a general programming concept/structure, transferable to other languages. Also I would be extremely hesitant to offer my opinion (good or bad) on a book unless I've read it myself.

Comment: Sagar, I skimmed the later book (Amazon's "Look Inside" feature) and all the code I saw was, as @mudasobwa said, "C code poorly and lazily translated to Ruby". However well the book teaches basic CS concepts (and the reviews are hardly glowing in that regard), anyone wanting to learn Ruby is very poorly served by this book. If the authors want to teach a procedure style they should have used a procedural language. Actually, I found the code closer to FORTRAN or BASIC than C.

Comment: @SagarPandya I don’t need to read the whole cookbook to assess it if the very first recipe includes fried nails in belladonna sauce.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you should be only checking `numbers <= floor(sqrt(i))`. The above code is unnecessarily checking numbers from `ceil(sqrt(i))` through `i/2`. It would give the correct answer, however.

In addition, this is not very Ruby-like code. It's terrible and the author should feel terrible (unless they intended to show you something bad in order for you to be amazed when you see how you can write it better!).

Here's the same code done in a more Ruby-like manner. Note that `prime?` can definitely be a one-liner, but I split things on to more lines readability in the context of the question:

```
def prime?(i)                       # Define a function that takes 1 parameter `i`
  MAX_NUM_TO_CHECK = Math.sqrt(i)   # No need to check numbers greater than sqrt(i)
  (2..MAX_NUM_TO_CHECK).all? do |j| # Return `true` if the following line is true for
                                    # all numbers [2,MAX_NUM_TO_CHECK]
    i % j != 0                      # true if `i` is evenly not divisible by `j`. Any
                                    # input that evaluates to false here is not prime.
  end
end

# Test primality of numbers [1,100]
(1..100).each {|n| puts "Prime ==> #{n}" if prime? n}
```

I think the biggest differences between your book and this code are:

- The algorithm is different in that we do not check all values, but rather limit the checks to `<= sqrt(i)`. We also stop checking once we know a number is not prime.
- We iterate over Ranges rather than keeping counters. This is slightly higher level and easier to read once you get the syntax.
- I split the code into two parts, a function that calculates whether a parameter is prime or not, and then we iterate over a Range of inputs `(1..100)`. This seems like a good division of functionality to me, helping readability.

Some language features used here not in your example:

- If statements can go after expressions, and the expression is only evaluated if the predicate (the thing after the `if`) evaluates to true. This can make some statements more readable.
- A [range](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html)  is written `(x..y)` and allows you to quickly describe a series of values that you can iterate over without keeping counters.
- Code inside

  `do |param1, ..., paramN| <CODE>; end`

  or

  `{|param1, ..., paramN| <CODE>}`

  is called a `block`. It's an anonymous function (a function passed in as a parameter to another function/method). We use this with `all?` and `each` here.
- `each` is used to run a block of code on each element of a collection, ignoring the return value
- `all?` can be used to determine whether a block returns `true` for every item in a collection.

If you're not familiar with passing code into functions, this is probably a little confusing. It allows you to execute different code based on your needs. For example, `each` runs the yielded block for every item in the collection.You could do anything in that block without changing the definition of `each`... you just yield it a block and it runs that block with the proper parameters. [Here is a good blog post to get you started on how this works and what else you can use it for](https://mixandgo.com/blog/mastering-ruby-blocks-in-less-than-5-minutes).

Comment: Rather than `return false` and then `true` at the end, I suggest `(2..Math.sqrt(i).floor).all? { |j|  (i % j) != 0 }`.

Comment: ^ Seconding this. In addition, note that methods such as `all?`, `any?` and `none?` are "lazy" - i.e. they will terminate as soon as the final result is already known. So if `i % 2 == 0`, then `3`, `4`, `5`, ... will not even be checked. This is what your code already does explicitly; but my point is that using `all?` will *not* cause a loss of performance.

Comment: You don't actually need the `floor` in the range. It only matters that the end is comparable to the iteration values.

Comment: Eric...could you explain this a bit more to me -- like what is your thinking process behind this?

Comment: Also (2..Math.sqrt(i).floor).each do |j| -- having a hard time understanding this... :(

Comment: What would you like more in terms of explanation?